# Redirecting a file from stdin, using fgets() to read information to array

Tags: c, arrays, stdin

```
int main() {
#define MEMSIZE 100
    int memory[MEMSIZE] = {0};
    int i = 0;
    char *temp = malloc(sizeof(100));

    fgets(temp, MEMSIZE, stdin);

    for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(memory)/sizeof(int)); i++) {
        memory[i] = temp[i];
    }

    for (n = 0; n < 10; n++) {    // Print contents
        printf("%d - %d\n", n, memory[n]); 
    }
}
```

So today I have what seems to be a very simple question. I am taking a file from         stdin, using:

```
./a.out < filename
```

My main goal is to take in the numbers provided in the file, and store them into a 1 dimensional array. My current use of `fgets()` works correctly, reading in line one and copying those elements into my 1D array (their ASCII values converted to int). Now, to read in my next lines, if I call `fgets()` again, the next line is read but it is then stored in the same place as the first values, thus overwriting them in my array in position 0-3. These values need to be stored successively in my array until EOF.

The file is in the format:

```
1234
5678
...
```

Comment: OK, and what's the problem?

Comment: Looks like you missed writing the question ?

Comment: Why'd you malloc for 100 bytes there?

Comment: `If i call fgets() again`....show us the code.

Comment: Sorry about that, had some issues with the question formatting. The malloc() was for my temp to be able to temporarily store the incoming string, which was then meant to be put into my array. I'm new to C, so im open to suggestions, even if my short bit of code is incorrect in any way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was simply calling it again manually, the exact same way it was done in line 7. I understand it will eventually need to be iterated, but i wanted to get down the process of reading just two lines first.

Comment: `fgets()` does not read integers, it reads characters. What you have in `memory` after the first loops is the character codes of the characters from the file. It also does not always read `MEMSIZE` characters, it reads up to that many characters and stops at the first line break, so you cannot assume that `MEMSIZE` characters were read. There are some other major mistakes in your program.

Comment: I've converted the ASCII values of the characters to their corresponding integers (unless there is a more efficient way of doing this). And yes, fgets() reads until the end of my first line, which brings up my main question: how to go about reading the following lines into my one dimensional array.

Comment: @C.j. You have to perform the code for reading one  line nested in another loop. Please, think about what condition to use to end this loop once you have consumed the whole file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MEMSIZE 100

int main() {
    int memory[MEMSIZE] = {0};
    int i,n;
    for (i = 0; i <MEMSIZE; i++){
        if(fscanf(stdin,"%d", (memory+i))==EOF){
            break;
        }
    }
   //i is the number of ints you got
   for (n = 0; n < i; n++) {    // Print contents
   printf("%d - %d\n", n, memory[n]); 
   }
   return 0;
}
```

1. I dont see a reason to use dynamic allocation over here as a temp variable.
2. If the file is list of numbers, just read as a number, no need for `fgets` over here, if you still want to read it as a string, have a look at `atoi` func
3. `sizeof(memory)/sizeof(int)`= `(sizeof(int)*MEMSIZE)/sizeof(int)`= `MEMSIZE`
4. You shouldn't just loop `MEMSIZE` times, you need to know when it `EOF`
5. I dont know why you assumed in the printing loop that 10 is enough, i changed it to `i` which is number of elements
6. You didnt define `n`

I hope that i helped.

Comment: Absolutely, thank you for the timely and thorough response. After posting, i had realized i posted it a bit prematurely. A couple of the variables were there because i only had a few values in my file, so i only printed out the first ten to get a feel for it. And i must admit, 3. made me feel a bit silly for thinking too hard. Again, thank you for the help!

Comment: `fscanf(stdin, format, ...);` is the same as `scanf(format, ...);`